# Is there a boost function for parallel_for in C++?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I need to do a parallel_for. Is there an easy implementation of this available in the standard C++ library, or in Boost? I have not found it.

By the way I am using Ubuntu. So I don't want Microsoft libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the functionality provided by openmp:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  // do some work
```

then compile with the `-fopenmp` flag if you are using gcc.

OpenMP is fantastic for relatively "pleasantly" parallel problems.

Comment: This is not standard C++ though.

Answer (score 8):

Since C++17 we have most algorithm as potentially parallel versions using the "execution policy" argument: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t

For a simple for-each, the algorithm would be`for_each`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

```
std::vector<int> v = get_tons_of_values();
std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](int i) {
   work(i);
});
```

In this example, we "ask" the lambda to be executed in parallel.

Note that the algorithm will decide itself it it will effectively run in parallel and how to run in parallel. For example if there is not enough values to make the cost of running parallel worth it, it will not run in parallel on most implementations. Consult your standard library implementation documentation to learn about the heuristics they will use.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally take a hard look at OpenMP.  Here's a good link to get you started and should explain how to write parallel for loops.

http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/

Disclaimer:  I'm not sure about standard C++ (including the latest standards) and have never used boost.  That said, I have used OpenMP when needing to do parallel processing in the past.